# What is temporary allocation?

Tags: memory-management

In C++, what is temporary allocation and when is it used?
Does such a thing even exist?
It was mentioned in the TA's course notes, but I couldn't find any info about it...

Comment: From http://publib.boulder.ibm.com: [Temporary objects (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr382.htm)

Comment: I don't think this deserves the C++ tag as it could apply to almost any compiler or language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When people say "temporaries" they often refer to rvalues. That is objects created and not bound to a variable name, thus not living outside the current statement. IE:

```
int foo()
{
     Do( Object() );
}
```

The created Object() is an rvalue which you may hear referred to as a temporary.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your TA may have been referring to objects without a name created during the evaluation of an expression.

```
SomeClass x(1), y(2), z(3);
SomeClass t = x + y + z;
```

The expression `x + y + z` invokes the `operator+()` twice; the result of the first is a temporary allocation (the result of the second initializes `t`).